# Laravel eloquent get relation count

Tags: php, laravel

I use Laravel 5.3.

I have 2 tables :

```
Articles
---------
id
cat_id
title
```

And

```
Category
---------
id
parent_id
title
```

I have defined my relations in my models :

```
// Article model
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}

// Category model
public function children() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Is there an easy way using Eloquent to have a list a categories with count of articles. The difficulty is that I want to group categories where `id_parent = 0`, i.e. I want to display only parent categories with count of articles in children.

I tried something like that :

```
    $category = new \App\Models\Category();
    $categoryTable = $category->getTable();

    return $category->leftJoin('article', 'article.cat_id', '=', 'category.id')
        ->whereIn('article.cat_id', function($query)
            {
                $query->select('cat_id')
                    ->from('categories')
                    ->where('categories.parent_id', ???)
                    ->orWhere($this->tableName .'.cat_id', $id);
            })
        ->groupBy('cat_id');
```

But I am lost...

Comment: How many levels of hierarchy will be there in the table ```category```?

Comment: Only 2 max, not more

Answer (score 123, accepted):

you can use `withCount()`. It is available from 5.3 version

for more info about eloquent visit : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Ah nice ! it works but I have 2 relations here. It works with the relation article -> category, but I need to include the children too.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! After we can access this values in the attribute of Entity ex: `$category->articles_count`

Comment: withCount is n+1 pretty much everytime I try it - fine for a small 10 row DB but just bump your rows to 1000 and suddently it does 1000 queries to count each item

Answer (score 40):

Define a `articles()` relation in your `Category` model as:

```
public function articles() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'cat_id');
}
```

Then you can try it as:

```
Category::where('parent_id', 0)->withCount('articles')->get();
```

Comment: But how to have the count of articles in category parent with children ?

Comment: Yes, but I will need the count of children's categories too. I mean if an article belongs to a children category, I need to count it.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `hasManyThrough()` Eloquent method to fetch all of the childrens' Articles, then add the article counts together in a nice little getter. I added the getter to the `$appends` array on the model to help illustrate it in the Tinker output.

```
class Category extends Model
{

    protected $appends = [
        'articleCount'
    ];

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function childrenArticles()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Article::class, Category::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function getArticleCountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->articles()->count() + $this->childrenArticles()->count();
    }
}
```

Here's the Tinker output:

```
Psy Shell v0.8.0 (PHP 7.0.6 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $cat = App\Category::first();
=> App\Category {#677
     id: "1",
     name: "Cooking",
     parent_id: null,
     created_at: "2016-12-15 18:31:57",
     updated_at: "2016-12-15 18:31:57",
   }
>>> $cat->toArray();
=> [
     "id" => 1,
     "name" => "Cooking",
     "parent_id" => null,
     "created_at" => "2016-12-15 18:31:57",
     "updated_at" => "2016-12-15 18:31:57",
     "articleCount" => 79,
   ]
>>>
```

If you want to restrict your Category query to ones that have children that have articles, you could do that using the `has()` method:

```
Category::has('children.articles')->get();
```

Here's more on the `has()` method:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

And the `hasManyThrough()` method:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Answer (score 2):

```
  public function NoOfStudent()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserAssignment::class,'assignment_id','id');
    }



$assignment = Assignment::select('id','batch_id','title','description','attachment','last_submission_date',DB::raw('(CASE WHEN type = 9 THEN "Quiz Type"  ELSE "Descriptive" END) AS assignment_type'),DB::raw('(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN "Assigned"  ELSE "Not Assigned" END) AS status'))
                      ->with('assignmentBatch:id,batch_number')
                      ->where('assignments.instructor_id',auth('api')->user()->id)
                      ->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
        if(!$request->user_id){
            $assignment =$assignment->withCount('NoOfStudent');
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In regards to `Carlos_E.`'s answer:

You can improve the query by using `whereHas` instead of `whereIn`:

```
$agents = Agents::whereHas('schedule')
  ->with('schedules')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$category
->where('categories.parent_id', 0)
->leftJoin('article', 'article.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
->select('categories.id', \DB::raw('COUNT(article.id)'))
->groupBy('categories.id')
->get();
```

The above query will get you category IDs and count of all articles that belong to the category.

After reading your question and comments again, if I understand correctly you want to get the count of all articles that belong to those categories (with parent_id = 0) + the count of articles that belong to sub categories (those with parent_id = (id of some category)).

Now I have no way of testing this easily, but I think something along these lines should work for that.

```
$category
->where('categories.parent_id', 0)
->leftJoin('article', 'article.cat_id', '=', 'categories.id')
->leftJoin('categories as c2', 'c2.parent_id', '=', 'categories.id')
->leftJoin('article as a2', 'a2.cat_id', '=', 'c2.id')
->select('categories.id', \DB::raw('(COUNT(article.id)) + (COUNT(a2.id)) as count'))
->groupBy('categories.id')
->get();
```

That beign said, I think you're better of having a column named count in categories and update it each time a new article gets added. For performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure somebody is still going through this, I was able to solve it the following way, suppose I have an Agent model and a Schedule model, i.e. one agent may have many schedules:

```
class Schedule extends Model {
  public function agent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Agent::class, 'agent_id');
  }
}

class Agent extends Model {
  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }

  public function schedules(){
    return $this->hasMany(Schedule::class);
  }
}
```

Well some agents may not necessarily have schedules assigned, thus, I filtered those before calling the `with()` method, like this:

```
$agents = Agents::whereIn(
    'id', 
    Schedule::distinct()->pluck('agent_id')
)->with('schedules')->get();
```

Hope this helps!.